# How can I delete from a LIST those rows that satisfy my where criteria?

Tags: c#

I have a list with rows that I would like to remove:

```
phraseSources.Where(i => i.JmdictMeaning == "Exception2" || i.JmdictMeaning == "Not found")
             .ToList()
```

Can someone give advice as to how I can delete the rows or even if that's possible. If not then I assume I will have to create another list but I would just like some advice on this.

Comment: Did you check all methods of `List<T>` starting from the word *Remove* in the doc? I'm pretty sure that you will find some useful method

Comment: what about not removing what you don't need, but selecting what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) should do the job.

```
phraseSources.RemoveAll(i => i.JmdictMeaning == "Exception2" || i.JmdictMeaning == "Not found");
```

side note: `RemoveAll` returns the number of removed items in case you care.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just Select & Reassign the result,

```
phraseSources = phraseSources.Where(i => !(i.JmdictMeaning == "Exception2" || i.JmdictMeaning == "Not found")).ToList()
```